# Batch file to run iexplore.exe with URL via Powershell via SSH from Linux machine

Tags: ssh, powershell, batch, clickonce

While accessing a Windows Pro VM via Remote Desktop, I can successfully run a batch file in Powershell by navigating to the folder and running ".\batchfile.bat" which contains:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://name.of.websitein.url.com?param=xyz"
```

There is a ClickOnce app (associated with the Windows user for security) that is run with this batch file. The parameter launches the app silently and updates a log file with downloaded information. When it works, it opens IE, downloads a file, close IE, opens the app and runs the command, then closes the app.

If I remote into the Windows machine via SSH **from a Linux machine**, the command prompt in SSH is Powershell. But if I try to run the batch file, it only shows Internet Explorer in the Task Manager. Nothing else happens and I have to end the task manually. If I do **"$out = .\batchfile.bat"** there is no output to read.

**I have attempted:** all various sorts of Invoke-Command, "cmd.exe", etc. All same results. I would like to prompt the normal behavior of the batch file if the user is logged in, or when account is locked. I am generally attempting this approach after endless failed attempts to run via Task Scheduler (Where it said it ran fine, but nothing actually happens).

How can a Linux machine interactively run commands as a user on a Windows machine in order to execute a script involving a ClickOnce app?

Comment: As for this...[While accessing a Windows Pro VM via Remote Desktop, I can successfully run a batch file in Powershell by navigating to the folder and running ".\batchfile.bat"]... and it should since you are logged in interactively with your profile. PowerShell natively does not allow you to run code in the context of the logged-on user. It is a Windows Security boundary. You'd have to use say PSExec ot the like to do that. If you are using a SchedueldTask for thios that is marks as run only when the user is logged-on, then there is no reason for SSH or remoteing at all. Just run PS as normal.

Comment: Is it possible to use PSExec from the same machine or only remotely? I am running SSH from a Linux machine. The Task Scheduler does not appear to work when set to "Run whether user is logged in or not". Seems to be a common problem. I would not use Windows otherwise, but the app that needs to be scheduled is Windows-only. I will need to find a method of interactive script-running, prompted by a remote connection from a Linux machine. I will update the question to include this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the ClickOnce app's developers - they claim a Windows 10 update recently caused the Task Scheduler to no longer work. Left with no other options...

...in the spirit of 90s computing I decided to use TinyTask with TaskScheduler to run a macro.